# What's the exact mechanism of oral tolerance?

Tags: immunology, immune-system

I have mainly two matters of confusion need to be clarified.

First question:

> The immune system does not necessarily kill everything hat has PAMPS, the bacteria living in the gut, have PAMPS (Pathogen-associated molecular pattern) in their surface, but they are not harmful to the body

Is this proposition correct?
and the second question is about my confusion of the following statement

> the mechanism by which the immune system tolerates the presence of the bacteria that live in the gut is not fully understood

So I am wondering, is there some textbooks or reference particularly talk about oral tolerance?
Moreover, I am especially curious about the fact that, since PAMPS trigger innate immune first rather than adaptive immune system, How can oral tolerance even avoid innate immune? is there some resources about that particular topic?

Comment: Please define acronyms that you use. And I wouldn't use chatGPT to study things....

Comment: @Bryan Krause Sorry about that, I just make the first citation  also a susceptible question which needs references, thank you!